# Changing values of a pandas dataframe based on other values in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am learning machine learning and generated a pandas dataframe containing the following columns `Id Category Cost_price Sold`. The shape of the dataframe is `(100000, 4)`.

Here the target variable is the Sold column`(1=Sold, 0=not sold)`. But no machine learning algorithm is able to get a good enough accuracy as all the columns in the dataframe is very random. To introduce a pattern to the dataframe I am trying to manipulate some of the values in the Sold column.

What i want to do is to change 6000 of the sold values to 1 where the cost_price is less than 800. But i am not able to do that.

I am new to machine learning and python. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index[df['cost_price'] < 800], 6000, replace=False), 'Sold'] = 1
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'Sold':[1,0,0,1,1,0] * 3,
         'cost_price':[500,300,6000,900,100,400] * 3,
})
print (df)
    Sold  cost_price
0      1         500
1      0         300
2      0        6000
3      1         900
4      1         100
5      0         400
6      1         500
7      0         300
8      0        6000
9      1         900
10     1         100
11     0         400
12     1         500
13     0         300
14     0        6000
15     1         900
16     1         100
17     0         400
```

---

```
df.loc[np.random.choice(df.index[df['cost_price'] < 800], 10, replace=False), 'Sold'] = 1
print (df)
    Sold  cost_price
0      1         500
1      1         300
2      0        6000
3      1         900
4      1         100
5      1         400
6      1         500
7      1         300
8      0        6000
9      1         900
10     1         100
11     1         400
12     1         500
13     1         300
14     0        6000
15     1         900
16     1         100
17     1         400
```

**Explanation**:

First filter index values by condition with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.index[df['cost_price'] < 800])
Int64Index([0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 16, 17], dtype='int64')
```

Then select random N values by [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html):

```
print (np.random.choice(df.index[df['cost_price'] < 800], 10, replace=False))
[16  1  7 13 17 12 10  6  5 11]
```

And last set `1` by index values with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you will randomly choose those 6000 rows.

```
idx = df.Sold[df.Cost_price < 800].tolist()
r = random.sample(idx, 6000)
df.Sold.loc[r] = 1
```

Comment: This changes all the Sold values where cost_price < 800 to 1. I want to change only 6000 values in the sold column where cost_price < 800. right now there are around 15000 values in the sold column where cost_price < 800

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html)

```
df.at[df.Sold[df.cost_price < 800][:6000].index, 'Sold'] = 1
```

If you randomly choose the rows use [`.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)

```
df.at[df[df.cost_price < 800].sample(6000).index, 'Sold'] = 1
```